# Why I can not 'get' a net-snmp table column but 'getnext' is ok?

Tags: net-snmp

I am trying to develop a **`net-snmp`** subagent, and came across something confusing.

Why I can not `get` a net-snmp table column but 'getnext' is ok in mib-browser?

I generated the code by `mib2c -c mib2c.iterate.conf`.

In mib-browser, **`get`** operation alerts: `can not retrieve data. unknown oid ...`,
**`getnext`** is okay.

So, why ? Does it have something to do with `mib2c.iterate.conf` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting snmpgetnext man page:

> the  variable that is lexicographically "next" in the remote entity's
>   MIB will be returned. For example: snmpgetnext -c public zeus
>   interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifType.1 will retrieve the variable
>   interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifType.2:
>   interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifType.2 = softwareLoopback(24)

in other words, the OID you are looking up does not exist so GET fails but the one lexicographically after it gets returned ok via GETNEXT.

```
$ snmpget -v 2C -c public myserver .1.3.6.1.2.1.4.31.3.1.3.2.9
IP-MIB::ipIfStatsInReceives.ipv6.9 = Counter32: 48

$ snmpgetnext -v 2C -c public myserver .1.3.6.1.2.1.4.31.3.1.3.2.9
IP-MIB::ipIfStatsInReceives.ipv6.10 = Counter32: 24

$ snmpget -v 2C -c public myserver .1.3.6.1.2.1.4.31.3.1.3.2.10
IP-MIB::ipIfStatsInReceives.ipv6.10 = Counter32: 24
```